# VegaLite.jl ignoring order of rows

Tags: julia, vega-lite

I am trying to plot a sorted bar chart in Julia using `VegaLite.jl` on the DataFrame sorted by the chosen key, but the bar chart completely ignores the order of the DataFrame. I've also tried to specify order on `y` in different ways, but that resulted in nothing (neither an error nor any effect on the sorting order).

Toy data and plotting:

```
using DataFrames
using VegaLite    
df2 = DataFrame(weight=rand(10), col_name=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"])
sort!(df2, [:weight], rev=true)
df2 |> @vlplot() + @vlplot(:bar, x=:col_name, y=:weight) + @vlplot(mark={:rule, strokeDash=[2,2], size=2}, y={datum=0.5})
```

How to specify the order of the bar chart so that it actually works?

Comment: I don't know anything about VegaLite.jl, but Vega-Lite itself does not maintain the order of the input unless you explicitly set `sort` to `null`. See https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/sort.html#no-sorting